# How do I format my Dropbox xml feed as a podcast feed?

Tags: dropbox, podcasts

I've set up my iTunes to download to Dropbox and now I have my podcasts saving to a dropbox folder.  I have subscribed to the the folders event feed and it gives me links to download the mp3 files but I want it to display like a podcast feed so my podcatcher recognizes the mp3 as a media enclosure and downloads it automatically.

Comment: heads up: even if you massage the dropbox feed (such as with http://www.feedcat.net/), and produce a valid, non-ssl (non-https) feed that you can plop into a podcatcher (such as itunes), the mp3 attachments still won't download: when you navigate to the mp3 attachment URL, dropbox serves you a "you don't belong here" page, and suggests you login.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem that the XML is formatted correctly to be picked up by podcaster. There doesn't appear to be a way of formatting the xml on the site through preferences so unless you use the developer API and write something I don't think you can reformat it.

Also Dropbox isn't really setup as a hosting service so if you have a free account, they tend to throttle heavy usage:

some discussion
http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=27170&replies=4#post-169337

help docs look for #45

hope that helps

Comment: That does help.  Just for the record, this would only be for personal use so I doubt I'd run into throttling issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest massaging the XML with Yahoo Pipes. Then use their generated XML as the input to your podcatcher.

Comment: How do you use Yahoo Pipes to create a media enclosure?